# gfortran 9.3.1 | SCL | missing findloc instrinsic?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intrinsics

Weird one (perhaps). Colleague and I trade back a large slug of Fortran code -- he is on a Windows machine, running mingw gfortran 9.2. Code compiles fine on his end.

But, on my end, no such luck -- I'm on Linux boxes (CentOS 7), running gfortran 9.3.1 under scl devtoolset. When I try to compile the exact same code, I get a fail at the end -- a few lines referring to a call to FINDLOC in one of the modules (something called estmat).

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: estmat.o: in function `filldm.3876': estmat.f90:(.text+0x1201): undefined reference to `_gfortran_findloc0_s1'
```

Was wondering if anyone can give me some advice? Is there a way to 'look for' FINDLOC on my box (irony accidental), or (more likely) if there is a packaging issue with devtoolkit for CentOS, is there something I can do to correct the problem?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: What versions of libgfortran do you have installed? Which one is visible to your linker?

Comment: Insufficient info is given; in particular, do you have more than one version o gfortran installed and/or more than one libgfortran.so.x installed.

Comment: Centos 7 defaults to gcc 4.8.5. As do any nuumber of people, and as noted in the OP,  I use SCL devtoolkit to compile using a more 'recent' flavour of gcc (gfortran). Using the scl bash shell, gfortran is 9.3.1.  I'm compiling a dynmically linked executable (not static) so am not explicitly calling libgfortran in the makefile.

Comment: Got cut off by the 5 minute time limit for edits - Centos 7 defaults to gcc 4.8.5. As do any nuumber of people, and as noted in the OP,  I use SCL devtoolkit to compile using a more 'recent' flavour of gcc (gfortran). Enabling the scl bash shell, gfortran is 9.3.1.  I'm compiling a dynmically linked executable (not static) so am not explicitly calling libgfortran in the makefile. If I revert to the older code, which doesn't use findloc, and ldd the successfully compiled and working executable, seems to indicate the right libgfortran being dynamically linked (/lib64/libgfotran.so.5).

Comment: If you have 2 libgfortran.so own your system, then you are likely linking against the wrong library.  Trying setting LD_RUN_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the 9.3.1 library.